# Should I always use torch.cuda.amp.autocast to speed up model inference?

Tags: machine-learning, pytorch, computer-vision

Pytorch supports [Automatic Mixed Precision (AMP)](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/amp.html) which will automatically convert parts of the network to half precision to speed up computation. I saw about a 23% speedup in inference time for my computer vision model when by simply adding `with torch.cuda.amp.autocast():` to my code.

This got me wondering whether I should always use  when doing model inference for 'free' speed gains, or if there are any downsides to doing so. If I understand correctly, there could be a small hit to model accuracy since we're dropping some information when reducing precision, but in practice this seems minimal. Are there other drawbacks?

Note: I'm only asking about model inference, not model training.